# Send strings from one console application to another

Tags: c#, console-application

**What I have:**

Two console applications (target framework 4). Application **A** does all the work, **B** displays status every 10 seconds. **A** runs through nearly 300,000 sql entries and performs miscellaneous work - output is most verbose and its hard to squeeze in general overview information about progress.

**What I need:**

My goal would be to have **A** first execute **B** and then "send" or pass strings over to **B** so that it can refresh itself with the new values of those strings. It would provide the user who is observing a good indication of what's going on with the whole operation.

What do you recommend to accomplish this. WCF, named pipes? I guess I could make app **A** the server and app **B** a client of some sorts.

**Visual example:** note that application A has about 10x more text (picture is just example)

[image: http://metroidcoven.com/idea.PNG]

Comment: Why have 2 apps? Why not multithread it and just update `A`?

Comment: Do you plan on having multiple **B** 's attach to a single **A**? Or have **B** be on a different machine?

Comment: There will only be a single A and single B - they both will exist in the same directory (local communication only). There will not be multiple instances launched. I am about to update the original question with a better explanation.

Comment: Mupltiple instances of A or B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make B first execute A.
- A write its verbose logging to standard output.
- B reads A's standard output (google how you can redirect input/output/err of a process)
- B aggregate information and write a clean log on its standard output.
- When A exits, B exits too.

Simple !

Answer (score 0):

When one process is spawning another, it can obtain its Standard Input/Output streams, so that you can read, write:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput